# While using Task.Delay for printing characters, how to prevent new KeyDown events occurring during print?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have many form control click events and keydown events for user control on a game I'm building. Much of the game details provided is in text that is printed to a read only text box using a Task.Delay method for slow printing:

```
async public void delayPrintLine(TextBox console, string output)
        {
            string s = output;
            char[] charArray = s.ToCharArray();
            s = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < charArray.Length; i++)
            {
                console.AppendText(charArray[i].ToString());
                await Task.Delay(80);
            }
            console.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
        }
```

Currently with all my button clicks or KeyDown events, if you do them fast or hold the key down continuously the printing interrupts and mixes together. Also it's causing data problems like if holding down 'a' for attack, you end up getting 10x the exp intended and 10 prints of "You Win".

I want to rewrite my events to not handle any other events while things are still printing or functions processing. I have tried using a flag to check and the code seems to make full sense but makes no change to the performance.

Global Flag:

```
public bool activeAction = false;
```

Attack Button Example:

```
private void attackBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!activeAction)
        {
            activeAction = true;
            heroAttack();
            currentHP.Text = "HP:  " + hero.HP;
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
        activeAction = false;
    }
```

Comment: Use a `Queue<string>` to queue the events up and then process them one after another?

Comment: Can this be done for more than just string printing though? Can I do this for all my event handling in the sense user click a button or presses a key and another event isn't registered until all tasks are completed?

Comment: I stumbled upon System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim which solved my issue with my Async methods but I still have the problem of events being able to be triggered extremely fast with a keydown. I want to have a way to limit user input events from triggering too quickly.